# Calculus based proof that If $f$ satisfies $x^TM_1 = f(x) x^T M_2$ then $f$ must be constant

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

I want to prove that if $f$ satisfies $x^TM_1 = f(x) x^T M_2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d, M_1, M_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}\ d \ge 2$ and $M_1 \ne 0$ and $M_2 \ne 0$, then $f$ must be a constant and $M_1$ must be a constant multiple of $M_2$.

Instead of proving this algebraically, I am trying to solve it through calculus. So I defined $g(x)= 0 = x^TM_1 - f(x) x^T M_2$. By calculating the jacobian of $g$ I can see that $0 = M_1 - (f(x) M_2 + \nabla f (x^TM_2))$. Through left-multiplication with $x^T$ I get that $(x^T \nabla f)(x^TM_2) = 0$.

So $f$ has the interesting property that gradient at $x$ is orthogonal to $x$. Does this property imply that $f$ must be constant?

I am now looking for some hints about how to move forward? How can I prove/disprove my  claim even in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If there exists a non-constant $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies $(x^T \nabla f) = 0$ then that would mean that that I have to find:

$f(x_1,x_2)$ s.t. 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = -x_2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = x_1$

I already tried to compute this in mathematica and although it's able to solve

```
DSolve[{D[f[a, b], a] * a + D[f[a, b], b] * b == 0}, f[a, b], {a, b}]
```

and suggests $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 / x_2$ but it's not able to solve

```
DSolve[{D[f[a, b], a] + b == 0, D[f[a, b], b] - a == 0}, f[a, b], {a, b}]
```

Does my PDE have no solution?

Comment: what are $M_1$ and $M_2$? matrices or vectors?

Comment: $M$ are matrices.

Comment: Could we assume that $M_1$ is nonsingular and $f$ continuous at $0$?

Comment: Thanks for the attempt below, unfortunately, I can't really assume that $M_1, M_2$ are nonsingular, or that $f(x)$ is continuous. In case you have a counterexample in mind then that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**It is wrong in general. The function $f$ need not be constant.**

Consider 
$$M_1 = M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x_1 \ne 0, \\ 0, & x_1 = 0. \end{cases} $$
It follows
$ M_1 - f(x) M_2 = 0 $ for $x_1 \ne 0$
and
$ x^T(M_1 - f(x) M_2) = 0 $ for $x_1 = 0$.

**If we may assume that $M_2$ is nonsingular and $f$ is continuous at $0$, then the statement holds.**

Let $a\in\mathbb R^d$ be such that $a^T M_2 \ne 0$. Thus, for every $t\in\mathbb R$ it follows
$$ f(ta)(ta)^T M_2 = (ta)^T M_1 = t a^T M_1 = t f(a) a^T M_2. $$
Since $a^T M_2 \ne 0$ we have $f(ta) = f(a)$ for every $t\ne 0$.

Now, if $f$ is continuous at $0$, it follows $f(ta) = f(0)$ for every $t\in\mathbb R$. And if $M_1$ is nonsingular, we have $a^T M_1\ne0$ for every $a\ne0$. Thus, $f$ is constant and $M_1$ is a constant multiple of $M_2$.

*Notes:*

$a^T M_1 \ne 0$ implies $a^T M_2\ne 0$ and $f(a)\ne 0$.

Comment: If $f$ could be any arbitrary function, then is it possible that $f$ may be non-constant? The assumption of non-singularity is not a deal breaker for me, but I really need to prove that no $f$ other than a constant could possibly satisfy this equality.

Comment: @Pushpendre: I found an counter example

Comment: @Pushpendre: Sorry, there was an index error in the example. Fixed it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the counterexample, I don't know why I was being so daft. I peeked inside the black box that was giving me $f$ and indeed $f$ can be assumed to be continuous. In fact I found that I can even take $f(x) = \frac{x^TM_1M_2x}{x^TM_2M_2^Tx}$. I can't believe that I didn't constrain my $f$ to be continuous!!

Comment: @Pushpendre: Your $f$ does imply that $M_2$ is nonsingular, otherwise $x^T M_2 M_2^T x$ might be zero.

Comment: Yeah, actually the real problem that I was solving was the following that if $M_1, M_2 \ne 0$ and if $\forall x, y x^TM_1y > 0 \implies x^TMy > 0$ then $M_1 = \lambda M_2$. Solving this problem boils down to solving the problem I posted. In my real problem I already constrain myself to situations where $M_2x \ne 0$ so its not a concern